# Adding to reflected Dictionaries

Tags: c#

I have a legacy class that looks like this:

```
public class LegacyBusinessObject
{
....(100 similar fields in total)
    public Dictionary<string, string> SomeBusinessValue1 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    public Dictionary<string, long> SomeBusinessValue2 = new Dictionary<string, long>();
    public Dictionary<string, decimal> SomeBusinessValue3 = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();
....
}
```

whereas the string key denominates the provider this value came from.

So for context: "SomeBusinessValue1" could be a weight measurement, that differs depending on the lab that did it.

I want to merge several of these monsters into one object using reflection:

```
    public LegacyBusinessObject Merge(Dictionary<string, LegacyBusinessObject> objects)
    {
        var result = new LegacyBusinessObject();
        //Loop through all the business object's fields
        foreach (var prop in typeof(LegacyBusinessObject).GetFields())
        {
            //Second loop through all the individual objects from different providers
            foreach (var ep in objects)
            {
                //Here I would need to test for all possivle value types that could 
                //be in the dictionary: <string, string>, <string, long>...
                //then cast to it and invoke the Add method like this:
                var propDictionary = prop.GetValue(result) as Dictionary<string, string>;
                propDictionary.Add(ep.Key, ep.Value);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Now this approach requires me to do a lot of clumsy casts for **propDictionary**. (I also tried consctructing the matching keyvaluepair<,> and an Activator to instance it; but i can't find a way to add this to another dictionary)

Can you think of a better way to perform this merge, that takes arbitrary dictionary value types?

Some more context:

I am getting a LegacyBusinessObject Obj1 with data from Lab A and Lab B that is stored in the dictionaries. No I am cleaning up the database and find out that another LegacyBusinessObject Obj2 has Data from Lab C and Lab D. As it turns out there was a mistake during ingestion and Obj1 and Obj2 are for the same product and have wrongfully been stored in two different LegacyBusinessObjects. I now want to merge the data to get a new LegacyBusinessObject with Data from Lab A through D

Comment: Yes, I can (in short, *reflection*), but you need to more precisely say what you want the *output* objects to look like. Talking at an information level, each provider has a `string` `SomeBusinessValue`, a `long` `SomeBusinessValue2`, and so on - so when you gather all these variously-typed business values, where do you want to put them? [Edit that information into your q](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50390621/edit) and you can be answered.

Comment: Why are you cast to propDictionary and then add to same dictionary propDictionary ?

Comment: @AakashM i added some context for clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite unclear what you are exactly asking, but:

```
public static LegacyBusinessObject Merge(Dictionary<string, LegacyBusinessObject> objects)
{
    var result = new LegacyBusinessObject();

    foreach (var prop in typeof(LegacyBusinessObject).GetFields())
    {
        var propDictionaryNew = (IDictionary)prop.GetValue(result);

        foreach (var dict in objects)
        {
            var propDictionaryOld = (IDictionary)prop.GetValue(dict.Value);

            foreach (DictionaryEntry de in propDictionaryOld)
            {
                propDictionaryNew[de.Key] = de.Value;

                // Or: 
                //((IDictionary)result).Add(de.Key, de.Value);
                // But be aware of exceptions if de.Key is present in multiple dictionaries
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

and then, to test it:

```
var lbo1 = new LegacyBusinessObject
{
    SomeBusinessValue1 = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "A1", "A2" }, { "B1", "B2" } },
    SomeBusinessValue2 = new Dictionary<string, long> { { "C1", 1 }, { "D1", 2 } },
    SomeBusinessValue3 = new Dictionary<string, decimal> { { "E1", 3 }, { "F1", 4 } },
};

var lbo2 = new LegacyBusinessObject
{
    SomeBusinessValue1 = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "G1", "G2" }, { "H1", "H2" } },
    SomeBusinessValue2 = new Dictionary<string, long> { { "I1", 5 }, { "J1", 6 } },
    SomeBusinessValue3 = new Dictionary<string, decimal> { { "K1", 7 }, { "L1", 8 } },
};

var result = Merge(new Dictionary<string, LegacyBusinessObject> { { "X", lbo1 }, { "Y", lbo2 } });
```

I'm cheating a little here... `Dictionary<,>` implements the pre-generics interface `IDictionary` (that is different from `IDictionary<,>`) that uses `object` as key and value. In this way I don't have to support the different value types. When using reflection with generic collections, a good trick is to see if the non-generic interfaces are enough to do what you need (because they are much easier to handle with reflection).

Comment: Perfect! I should've examined the interfaces more carefully.